# jquery: Fill data from ajax call to select

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

method from external API returns data like:

```
[{"deviceName":"Srba","deviceId":"17d0d7a199b1"},{"deviceName":"357122388","deviceId":"2b4473f6e781"}...]
```

I call it from my page:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'url',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (selectValues, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (selectValues != null) {
                    $("#tablet").empty();
                    $("#tablet").append("<option value='0'>--Select--</option>");
                    $.each(selectValues, function (key, value) {
                        $('#tablet')
                            .append($("<option></option>")
                                .attr("value", key)
                                .text(value));
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, ex) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });
```

But I get an error and callback function `error` is called

[image]

How can I understand, what is wrong and why it happens?

Comment: show what error you have having

Comment: is your url request : 'url' ?, I think you must change the url to the right url of api.

Comment: @guradio, added error data, but I don't understand, how it can help me, because most of them - some functions...

Comment: @rapaelec, I just hid correct url. It calls correctly address

Comment: ok so try to change your dataType to ‘json’ please

Comment: change datatype from `jsonp` to `json`

Comment: @rapaelec  but I do request from https to http